# Setting a color using an attribute, folium, python dataframe

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I would like CircleMarker to set the color using an argument, is there such a possibility? I have dataframe something like this below:

```
lon     lat  segment
ABMF00GLP  -61.528  16.262       41
ABPO00MDG   47.229 -19.018       71
ACRG00GHA   -0.207   5.641       16
AGGO00ARG  -58.140 -34.874        4
AIRA00JPN  130.600  31.824       20
...            ...     ...      ...
YKRO00CIV   -5.240   6.871       16
ZAMB00ZMB   28.311 -15.426       90
ZECK00RUS   41.565  43.788       67
ZIM200CHE    7.465  46.877       81
ZIM300CHE    7.465  46.877       81
```

I can add markers with the same color like below, unfortunately I don't know how to make it segment dependent.

```
for x in df.index:
    folium.CircleMarker(list(np.array(df.loc[x])),
                      popup=x,
                      radius=3,
                      color = "red",
                      ).add_to(m)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce a continuous colormap and set minimum and maximum values in segment columns. Takes a segment value as an argument in the marker color setting. See this for [more information](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Colormaps.ipynb) about colormaps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import folium
import branca.colormap as cm

data = '''
id lon     lat  segment
ABMF00GLP  -61.528  16.262       41
ABPO00MDG   47.229 -19.018       71
ACRG00GHA   -0.207   5.641       16
AGGO00ARG  -58.140 -34.874        4
AIRA00JPN  130.600  31.824       20
YKRO00CIV   -5.240   6.871       16
ZAMB00ZMB   28.311 -15.426       90
ZECK00RUS   41.565  43.788       67
ZIM200CHE    7.465  46.877       81
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

linear = cm.LinearColormap(["green", "yellow", "red"], vmin=df['segment'].min(), vmax=df['segment'].max())

m = folium.Map([df['lat'].mean(), df['lon'].mean()], tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=2)

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row.lat, row.lon],
                      popup=row.id,
                      radius=3,
                      color = linear(row.segment),
                      ).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Geopandas has very useful [interactive mapping](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/interactive_mapping.html#Interactive-mapping). When you call this method on geopandas dataframe, it will return folium map instance.

For you to use color the markers based on the `segment` value, simply do:

```
df.explore(
     column='segment')
```

Please note that you dataframe has to be geopandas dataframe, not just pandas dataframe.